# What do I have to do to cover the figure number and caption with a frame?

Tags: framed, kile

What do I have to do to cover the figure number and caption with a frame?

[image]

The code I am using for this is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[bb=0 0 268 167, fbox]{fig1.jpg}
     % fig1.jpg: 357x223 pixel, 96dpi, 6x4 cm, bb=0 0 268 167
     \caption{ The circles $A_C$ and $B_C$ intersect only at the point $C$.}
    \label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Code changed to a minimal working example. Your document seen a `book` type class rather than an `article`, but it seem irrelevant for the question. Please always show a minimal but compilable code, so others can play with this code (easier answer = more chance of answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a framed `minipage` in the float:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Your caption}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not working in my tex@fran

Comment: @David I cannot guess what are you doing. My MWE is basic code that should work in any TeXlive or MikTeX installation if you have the picture `example-image-a` (included with the `mwe` package of both distributions). Edit your question to replace the minimal (not)working-example with a copy of your real tex file, but **reduced** as possible (in the preamble and body text), but still  **compilable** (it should star with `\documentclass{...` and end with `\end{document}`) and still showing your problem (and only this problem: be careful when deleting chunks of code!).